# react redux router is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
export function loginSuccess(response){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch({ response, type: types.LOGIN })
      console.log(getState())
      router.transitionTo("/profile")
  };
}
```

Here when `console.log(getState())` it gives `router` object.. but it does not have `transitionTo` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `router` variable is undefined. If `getState()` contains the router object then you need to assign it in order to use it.

```
let { router } = getState();
```

From here on out you can use the `transitionTo` method since the `router` object is now defined.

Comment: router object has no transitionTo method.. when I do this it gives me transitionTo is not a function error.. I tried doing `getState().router.transitionTo` but same issue

Comment: Then perhaps you have the  `location` object or `history` object at hand instead?

Comment: yes I have location object.. how can I call redirect from that ?

Comment: `router` object has `location` object.. how can I redirect with this object ?